# Why I cannot read this text file with numerical data from my C program?

Tags: c, file-io, text-files

I have a text file with 4096 numerical data that I am trying to read with a C source. But, my program does not work at all. Just show "fail to open a file"

Why?

But, if I try another text file, it works.

Please tell me what the problem is!

Heads from two text files are below:

*head of cannot_read.txt

```
   50129.248000000000     
   50129.248000000000     
   2193.2479999999996     
   2193.2479999999996     
   2961.2479999999996     
   2577.2479999999996     
   1809.2479999999996     
   81.247999999999593     
   721.24799999999959     
   1745.2479999999996
```

*can_read.txt

```
3.45654675443
1.23536565353
123123.353535
3.45654675443
1.23536565353
123123.353535
3.45654675443
1.23536565353
123123.353535
3.45654675443
```

My program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    int j;
//    float fval[4097];
    long double fval[4097];

    FILE * fp;
//           fp = fopen("/home/changwan/C/can_read.txt","r");
             fp = fopen("/home/changwan/C/cannot_read.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
            puts("fail to open a file!");
            return -1;
    }

   n = 0;
//   while (fscanf(fp, "%f", &fval[n++]) !=EOF)
   while (fscanf(fp, "%Lf", &fval[n++]) !=EOF)
       ;

   for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
       printf("fval[%d]=%Lf\n", i, fval[i]);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably this file is not there, where you think it is. Use `perror` to understand exactly why `fopen` fails.

Comment: C doesn't support the `~` prefix, that's a feature of the shell and a handful of other applications.

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text as *text* into your question.

Comment: Terminology: C is not a scripting language, and C source files are not "scripts".  You can use "source" or "source file".  You can also use "program" if one file contains a whole program, or if you are referring to the whole collection of source files that comprises a program.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%Lf", &fval[n++]) !=EOF)` is not going to work if the input file contains invalid data.  If `fscanf` returns 0 (which it will do if the input file contains certain data), this will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks all of you. Constructive comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fopen()` function does not support the `~` symbol. Check out the `realpath()` function and the difference between absolute and relative paths.

Comment: Ok. My question was too bad (I revised). If my file path is right, what is the problem? As you can see my attachment, there is a difference between the head of the two files. One has no blank in front of the number, while the other has some blank before the number. Then, what change should be made in the "fscanf"?

Comment: Add some referred linked to support your answer.

Comment: I add new materials for my question!

Comment: Ok! it worked! I think the path was wrong! Thank you for everyone!

Comment: @ChangwanSun feel free to accept an  answer if it has helped you !